# UILabel moving Left or Right in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Can any one please tell me how I move UILabel to left or right, depending on the input of a user(finger swipe left moves left, finger swipe right moves right, finger press right moves right, finger press left moves left? Using Swipe gesture recognizer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should add your swipe gesture recognizers, for example in viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
   swipeRight.direction = .Right
   view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

   let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
   swipeRight.direction = .Left
   view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

   let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
   swipeDown.direction = .Down
   view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)

   let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
   swipeDown.direction = .Up
   view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)

}
```

Then you should implement the method to move the labels on swipe:

```
func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

switch swipeGesture.direction {
        case .Right:

           // Move Label to the right
           yourLabel.frame.origin.x += 100

        case .Down:
           // Move Label down
           yourLabel.frame.origin.y += 100

        case .Left: 
           // Move Label to the left
           yourLabel.frame.origin.x -= 100

        case .Up:
           // Move Label up
           yourLabel.frame.origin.y -= 100
    }
}
```

If you want to move your label animated, use `view.animateWithDuration`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UISwipeGestureRecognizer for swiping left or right and UIView's animations for animating!